# C# - Shortest path map finding

Tags: c#

I'm about to try to write a simple program in C#, it's like map finding.

I've a picture of city / or district ( it's const ) and I'll add a database to this program to store variables, points. I'll use the [Floyd-Warshall algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm) to find the shortest path and I'll draw the path in the image (by coordinates, I think).
This is the first time I've written a real program in C# so how should I implement this one. ;)

Thanks so much for reading!

Comment: Are you asking which technologies/frameworks that could help with the implementation?

Comment: Comments added from a non-answer: My question exactly is how I begin to implement this like creating Gui, database, get values from it, how can I draw a path and how to know I find a shortest path depends on street :) I've implemented F-W before, the problem is the UI and database calls :)

Answer (score 0):

If I were just after proof of concept, I'd download Microsoft's free Visual C# 2008 Express Edition, load up a simple form and place a picturebox on it and set the image to your constant picture, the Dock property to Fill, and then put some code in the Paint Event:

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Red), new Point(0, 0), new Point(100, 200));
}
```

Et voila! A red diagonal line.